# usar una imagen en un juego y remplazar rectángulo

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de implementar un juego, por ahora el jugador lo tengo identificado como un rectángulo de color rojo, pero quiero remplazarlo por una ***imagen png*** que tengo, la verdad no tengo claro de cómo hacer esto, pues estoy recién comenzando a introducirme en este proyecto, espero me puedan ayudar.

Acá inicializo la variable ***`player`***:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.SurfaceHolder
import android.view.SurfaceView

class GamePanel(context: Context) : SurfaceView(context), SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private val thread: MainThread
    private val r = Rect()

    private val player: RectPlayer
    private var playerPoint: Point? = null
    private var obstacleManager: ObstacleManager? = null

    private var movingPlayer = false

    private var gameOver = false
    private var gameOverTime: Long = 0

    init {
        holder.addCallback(this)

        thread = MainThread(holder, this)

        player = RectPlayer(Rect(100, 100, 200, 200), Color.rgb(255, 0, 0))
```

---

Y esta es la función  ***`RectPlayer`***:

```
package com.example.user.kotlinmetry

import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.Point
import android.graphics.Rect

class RectPlayer( var rectangle: Rect, private var color: Int) : GameObject {

    init{
        this.rectangle = rectangle
        this.color = color
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val paint = Paint()
        paint.setColor(color)
        canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint)
    }

    override fun update() {
    }

    fun update(point: Point) {
        rectangle.set(point.x - rectangle.width() / 2, point.y - rectangle.height() / 2, point.x + rectangle.width() / 2, point.y + rectangle.height() / 2)
    }
```

Estoy reciclando un proyecto que encontré, pues quiero ocupar una característica que encontré ya intente varias cosas, pero no me ha resultado, sé que tengo que usar la función:

```
Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.imagen_png);
```

Pero no me ha resultado nada.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cargar el bitmap con :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player);
```

Y para cargarlo en pantalla :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     ...
     canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect_de_tu_player, null);
     ...
}
```